# Minecraft Armor Modding java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Tags: java, minecraft

So, I have just started adding an armor set to my Minecraft mod for 1.6.4. Also, I have started a topic on the Minecraft Forums, but like always, tons of people view it, but never bother to answer. So, my problems is that I have registered the armor material like so:

```
             public static EnumArmorMaterial ArmorSetPyro = EnumHelper.addArmorMaterial("EMBER", 45, new int[]{3, 8, 6, 3}, 50);
```

When I run the mod in the Eclipse environment, I recieve this error:

```
            Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
            2014-03-30 10:03:28 [INFO] [STDOUT]     at              net.minecraft.item.EnumArmorMaterial.getDamageReductionAmount(EnumArmorMaterial.java:50)
            2014-03-30 10:03:28 [INFO] [STDOUT]     at              net.minecraft.item.ItemArmor.<init>(ItemArmor.java:50)
            2014-03-30 10:03:28 [INFO] [STDOUT]     at              brett.sc.armor.ArmorSetPyro.<init>(ArmorSetPyro.java:14)
            2014-03-30 10:03:28 [INFO] [STDOUT]     at              brett.sc.common.SwordConjuring.<clinit>(SwordConjuring.java:165)
```

I followed EsvDefCon's armor tutorial and did everything exactly as he did, and yet my code simply wants to be annoying and not work. I understand that it's a problem with this part:

```
            new int[]{3, 8, 6, 3}
```

Because that's the damage reduction part. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Looks like the values are at index 0-3, and you're trying to read index 4 (ie out of bounds) at EnumArmorMaterial.java line 50. Why that happens is pretty hard to even guess without seeing the code that is involved.

Comment: I googled for the code, but it looks like I need to create an account on "compilr.com" to see it.  No thanks.  But I think the OP has enough information to work this out for himself now.

Comment: Arrays have a 0 index, so like the error states, you are trying to access an item in your array (element 4) that doesn't exist (the last element in your array is 3 - you have 0, 1, 2, 3 (no 4).  

Start counting at 0 instead of 1.